# How to create objects that can process and respond to arbitrary messages

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, messages are strings. How to define how to respond to arbitrary strings as messages, instead of predefine a set of messages and the responses for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MessageResponder
  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    "You called #{method}(#{args.map(&:inspect).join(', ')})#{' with block' if block}"
  end
end

responder = MessageResponder.new
responder.foo(3, 7)
# => You called foo(3, 7)
```

If a message does not correspond to any of the class methods, then the method called `method_missing` is invoked. You can see in the example what it receives. If you override that, you can respond to any message.

Answer (score 1):

Messages without a matching method are sent to `method_missing`. You can implement that to respond however you like.